# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl

Tags: java, ant, jar, weblogic-10.x

I have a Java Ant project which creates a executable Jar in order to connect to JNDI through T3 protocol (Weblogic). I have NO problem to establish a connection and to list JNDIs:)
For example, I can see that the ***weblogic.management.j2ee.mejb.Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl mejbmejb_jarMejb_EO*** JNDI is accessible.

My executable Jar contains weblogic classes (classes stored in weblogic.jar).

I use this Ant code to create my executable Jar:

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile">
            <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/JndiConnection.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
                <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                    <include name='**/*.jar'/>
                </zipgroupfileset>
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${ant.project.name}" />
                    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${ant.project.name}.jar" /> 
                </manifest>
            </jar>
</target>
```

The lib directory (${lib.dir}) contains ***wlfullclient.jar*** and ***mejb.jar*** at least.

Now, I would like to query Names of JMOs (see source code in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13736/toc.htm#JEEMG106). I have put this code in my project (see "Example 1 Querying Names of JMOs" in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13736/toc.htm#JEEMG106). 
In my executable Jar, I have all classes stored in *mejb.jar*:

```
Archive:  mejb.jar

  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      147  2011-11-15 09:01   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2011-11-15 09:01   META-INF/
      882  2011-11-15 09:01   META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
      857  2011-11-15 09:01   META-INF/weblogic-ejb-jar.xml
        0  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/
        0  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/
        0  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/
        0  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/
     6622  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl.class
     2284  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImplRTD.xml
     7442  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.class
     7288  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl_WLSkel.class
     2548  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl.class
     1161  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImplRTD.xml
     4976  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl_1036_WLStub.class
     4200  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl_WLSkel.class
     2414  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl.class
     1724  2011-11-15 09:01   weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Intf.class
      290  2011-11-15 09:01   _WL_GENERATED
---------                     -------
    42835                     19 files
```

Some classes in my executable Jar:

```
$ 7z l JndiConnection.jar | grep 'weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/'
2011-11-15 09:01:30 .....         6622         2303  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl.class
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         2284          553  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImplRTD.xml
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         7442         2565  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.class
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         7288         2844  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl_WLSkel.class
2011-11-15 09:01:30 .....         2548         1128  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl.class
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         1161          425  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImplRTD.xml
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         4976         1845  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl_1036_WLStub.class
2011-11-15 09:01:32 .....         4200         1890  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl_WLSkel.class
2011-11-15 09:01:30 .....         2414          926  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl.class
2011-11-15 09:01:30 .....         1724          661  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Intf.class
2008-07-25 17:38:32 .....         3231         1225  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/MejbBean.class
2011-11-15 08:55:40 .....         3231         1225  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/MejbBean.class
```

When I would like to run the jar (***java -jar JndiConnection.jar*** or ***java -cp '.:JndiConnection.jar:/path/to/libs/*' JndiConnection***), I have the following error:

```
Java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
at weblogic.management.j2ee.mejb.Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.queryNames(Unknown Source)
at Mejb.getAllJMONames(Unknown Source)
```

I don't undestand because I have *weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl* in my executable Jar. I think the Jar can't find it but I don't know why...

I have tried with the manifest:

```
Main-Class: JndiConnection
Class-Path: . JndiConnection.jar
```

and:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_65-b32 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: JndiConnection
Class-Path: .
```

JndiConnection.class is in the root directory:

```
Listing archive: JndiConnection.jar
Path = JndiConnection.jar
[...]
2014-12-31 16:54:26 .....         7645         3454  JndiConnection.class
[...]
```

I use ***Apache Ant 1.8.4*** because I need to have more than 65535 entries in my zip file (jar).
I have this error when I use the last Ant version (**1.9.3**):

```
Problem creating jar: archive contains more than 65535 entries.
```

**- Edit 1**

I can see a ***Mejb*** instance in ***Deployments->Monitoring->EJB***.

The check box "***Management EJB Enabled***" is enabled in the ***General*** Configuration of the ***webcenter***. If I have understood, this checkbox allows the administrator to enable or disable the MEJB.

I see a line which contains information about the Mejb application in ***Deployments->Monitoring->EJB***. This line shows that 77 connections have been established to the MEJB application and 77 failures.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Notice: I'm using the version 10.3.6.0 of Weblogic.

Comment: My executable Jar contains that:

Answer (score 0):

If your executable JAR is JndiConnection.jar, then in your Manifest you should not be referencing itself. The Class-Path is used to refer to dependent jars for example which are not included in the executable JAR. If you have no dependency for other classes or JARs outside the scope of the JAR, then you can try this:

```
Main-Class: com.bla.bla.JndiConnection
Class-Path: .
```

Don't forget that you have to show the package for the class too. So provide the fully-qualified name of the class.

Aslo in the Weblogic admin console, can you see that there is any instance(for Mejb_dj5nps) in the bean pool?

Here is how you can check your Bean's existence:
**In the WebLogic Console: Go to Deployments->Monitoring->EJB (if you deployed EJB, you should see it here)**

Attaching a screenshot where you see I have deployed a remote EJB for testing
[image]

In your executable JAR you have:

```
2008-07-25 17:38:32 .....         3231         1225  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/MejbBean.class
2011-11-15 08:55:40 .....         3231         1225  weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/MejbBean.class
```

This caused a problem.

**You are hopefully using  WebLogic Server 10.x or a later release**. Then just use **wlfullclient.jar** and **do not use mejb.jar**. **Remove mejb.jar from ${lib.dir}** and rebuild your executable JAR.

Check this link about wlfullclient.jar [Client-side Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/basics.html#wp1069994)

Comment: I can't see the ***Mejb_dj5nps*** instance but the ***Management EJB Enabled*** check box is enabled in the General Configuration of the webcenter...

Comment: There is a line in the JNDI list which contains an instance Mejb: ***weblogic.management.j2ee.mejb.Mejb_dj5nps_EOImpl mejbmejb_jarMejb_EO***

Comment: Is it a server-side error or a client-side error? I'm thinking it's perhaps a server side error ....

Comment: How are you deploying? Using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Nop. I'm using Geany/Java/Javac/Ant under Linux. I don't use Eclipse because i's a small java project.

Comment: Can you verify that your client JAR(JndiConnection) has only one class of Mejb_dj5nps_Impl? If there are multiple copies of this class in JAR then it will be a problem.

Comment: There is only one ***Mejb_dj5nps_Impl class***. ***7z l JndiConnection.jar | grep Mejb_dj5nps_Impl*** returns only one line: ***weblogic/management/j2ee/mejb/Mejb_dj5nps_Impl.class***

Comment: In the WebLogic Console, ***Deployments->Monitoring->EJB*** I have a MEJB line.

Comment: However, the ***Pooled Beans Current Count*** column in my MEJB line is equal to 0. **Access Total Count** >= 77

Comment: I think the problem is in the executable JAR you have two copies of same class MejbBean. Check the answer, I edited again.

Comment: I have delete a MejbBean.class and there is always the same error. I have use the ***duplicate="preserve"*** option in Ant to have only one class. The executable Jar contains only one ***MejbBean.class***. Why there is two MejbBean.class in my Jar? There is no other Jar (append to my executable Jar) which contains this class.

Comment: Just use wlfullclient.jar from ${lib.dir} when building executable jar. Check the answer it has a link which may help.

Comment: I have tried to use ***wlfullclient.jar*** ONLY (and not mejb.jar): same error: **java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.management.j2ee.mejb.Mejb_dj5nps_Impl**. If I don't use ***mejb.jar***, I have not ***Mejb_dj5nps_Impl.class*** in my executable Jar. I'm lost... Is it a client-side error or server-side error? ***wlfullclient.jar*** doesn't contains ***Mejb_dj5nps_Impl.class***.

Comment: If I use ***duplicate="preserve"*** to generate the Jar with Ant, I can't list JNDI because I have this error during the execution of my executable Jar: ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to generate class for weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_1036_WLStub at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubGenerator.generateStub(StubGenerator.java:790)***

Comment: Try undeploying your MEJB application from server(it should not show in Deployments->Monitoring->EJB) and test the JAR.

Comment: I don't know how to undeploy the MEJB. I have try to uncheck the checkbox ***Management EJB enabled*** in the webcenter and I see always the MEJB line in ***Deployments->Monitoring->EJB***. The line ***weblogic.management.j2ee.mejb.Mejb_dj5nps_HomeImpl MEJB*** is always in the JNDI list.